# How to find the most consecutive weeks

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate-functions

My data:

```
INSERT INTO martin_test (id, user_id, created_at) VALUES
  ('1bb20295-fd7b-4918-a496-313e5babd482', 'abc', '2024-01-04 15:54:51')
, ('08565423-3371-4720-abb3-80c7aef8333d', 'abc', '2024-01-11 15:54:51')
, ('b17443fe-5a4f-4b7c-934d-3d2910a65f44', 'abc', '2024-01-18 15:54:51')
, ('3d267dc3-ee86-44e9-b1fe-fd918a64b77c', 'abc', '2024-02-01 15:54:51')
, ('d28d73d3-bc9c-4192-998a-a6bafce604a5', 'abc', '2024-02-08 15:54:51')
, ('401d38f8-d277-4605-af33-b4a9bd2eef25', 'abc', '2024-02-22 15:54:51')
, ('b804fa29-23af-4d93-a5c9-187767fec3c9', 'abc', '2024-02-29 15:54:51')
;
```

My query:

```
SELECT *,CASE WHEN gap_weeks > 1 THEN 1 END, avg(CASE WHEN gap_weeks > 1 THEN 7 END) OVER (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY week_number) AS grp_avg,
    sum(CASE WHEN gap_weeks > 1 THEN 6 END) OVER (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY week_number) AS grp_sum,

           COUNT(CASE WHEN gap_weeks > 1 THEN 1 END) OVER (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY week_number) AS grp
    FROM (
      SELECT user_id,
             week_number,
             lag(week_number) OVER (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY week_number) AS pre_week_number, 
             week_number - lag(week_number) OVER (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY week_number) AS gap_weeks
      FROM (
        select distinct EXTRACT(
              WEEK 
              FROM 
                CAST(created_at AS DATE)
            ) AS week_number ,user_id  from martin_test ) AS a
    ) AS subquery1
```

Why is abc's grp '0.1.2.3'? I don't know why the next gap_weeks > 1 then grp will be added 1), and how's count & avg & sum (case when) over(PARTITION by) works?
[My results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x7HtO.png)

My requirement is:
*"Find the most consecutive weeks!"*

I found this [related blog post](https://medium.com/@williamwnsong/find-the-highest-consecutive-days-%E6%9C%80%E5%A4%9A%E9%80%A3%E7%BA%8C%E5%A4%A9%E6%95%B8-11c72661f074).

[Supplementary Notes]
[Result2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1mvFf.png)
Sorry,My questions are
1.Why gap_weeks more than 1,the grp increasing is "1" not "3" (see my photo Result2)
2.Why week_number (1&2&3 is a group,5%6 is a group,8&9&10 is a group,12 is a group)

Comment: I failed to decode the bulk of your explanation. So I'll focus on your declared objective.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I focused on your declared objective:

> *Find the most consecutive weeks!*

Can be done like this:

```sql
SELECT dense_rank() OVER (ORDER BY count(*) DESC) AS rank
     , user_id
     , count(*) AS consecutive_weeks
     , concat_ws(' - ', min(week_nr), max(week_nr)) AS week_range
FROM (
   SELECT *
        , week_nr - row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY week_nr) AS grp
   FROM  (
      SELECT DISTINCT user_id, extract(week FROM created_at)::int AS week_nr
      FROM   martin_test
      ) sub
   ) sub1
GROUP  BY user_id, grp
ORDER  BY consecutive_weeks DESC;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/kVVav3Cj)

Consecutive week numbers would increase in lockstep with the result of `row_number()` over the same partition. If you subtract that row number from actual week numbers (`week_nr`), consecutive weeks get the same `grp` number. Then just aggregate.

Works only for weeks of the same year, obviously. Else you need to do more.
Related:

- [Select longest continuous sequence](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/35389/3684)

##### Notes

Not sure what you are trying to achieve with the `CASE` expressions. I presume you don't need them.

`EXTRACT` works just fine with `timestamp` input. No need to cast to `date`. But consider `timestamptz` instead of `timestamp`, if multiple time zones may be involved.

The cast to integer `::int` is optional. Cheaper to operate with `integer` instead of `numeric` for just week numbers.

Comment: Thank you for your response and explanation. Your answer was helpful to me, and I also learned another approach. 
However, my question is regarding "COUNT(CASE WHEN gap_weeks > 1 THEN 1 END) OVER (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY week_number) AS grp". Why does the grp automatically increment by 1 when gap_weeks is greater than 1? For example, if abc week_number=5, why does grp change from 0 to 1 instead of another number?
The second question is, why is it grouped according to different consecutive weeks?

Comment: The "CASE" is gpt's answer.After your explanation, I think I don't need it to resolve "Find the most consecutive weeks by people". Thank you very much!!

Comment: Sure,but can u tell me how it work "COUNT(CASE WHEN gap_weeks > 1 THEN 1 END) OVER (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY week_number) AS grp" ?

Comment: That's an awkward window function. Burns down to: `COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE gap_weeks > 1) OVER (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY week_number) AS grp`. Effectively also forms groups like my superior query, by increasing the number whenever the gap was more than a week.

Comment: Sorry,i'm trying to make you understand my quesiton with above "Supplementary Notes"